# Which originally non-English novel or story has had the widest reception in English-language SF as measured in number of citations?

Tags: short-stories, novel, languages, influences

I'm trying to understand how big the influence of translated SF is in the English speaking world. Part of the question is which is the single most influential work from outside.

So, which story or novel that was not originally published in English has been most often cited in other works, as measured by number of citations in Google Scholar?

Comment: Honorable mention shoutout to Čapek's Czech-language play "R.U.R.", which introduced the word "robot". A virtually unknown work, but the word is so common in SciFi that I feel it deserves mentioning.

Comment: [The Little Prince](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Prince).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - is Exuperie (sp?) SciFi? I mean it has some SciFi trappings, but I'm unsure he himself classified Little Prince as such.

Comment: You mean "how _small_ the influence of translated SF is in the English speaking world", especially when you compare to the massive influence of English language SF translated in others.

Comment: **<deleted comments>**  Folks, let's skip the whole 'is the Bible fiction?' discussion, this isn't the site for that.

Comment: Ok I must have missed or forgotten the question was closed. I'm puzzled the google scholar cites are seen as a *good* criterium for reception but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Also I wonder if the tireless translation work by Ken Liu in the last years changed the answer to this ...

Comment: I'm curios what people who know more about literature than me think about quantifiying influence, and asked on Lit. SE: https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12246/4386

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I'm pretty sure **[Jules Verne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne)** is going to be a frontrunner of this. He wrote originally in French, and is the second most translated author in the world (after Shakespeare and just before Agatha Christie). He has had a major influence on Science Fiction for more than a hundred years, with multiple screen adaptations.

EDIT: The question asked for a work. It's hard to choose between his most popular science fiction works (20,000 Leagues Under the Sea; Journey to the Centre of the Earth; From the Earth to the Moon) and I can't find sales figures for each, but if I had to guess it has to be 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea.

Comment: Can't argue with choice of Jules Verne, was going to suggest him myself. As a distant second, maybe Karel Čapek, especially his *R.U.R* and *War with the Newts*?

Comment: Great answer. Verne's work is so ubiquitous and accessible that it's easy to forget he wrote in French.

Comment: When I first posted, saw yours beat me by 6 mins. Must have been composing answers at the same time and yours posted first.  Have to give you an upvote.

Comment: But yours is more complete. So you get an upvote too.

Comment: The question actually asked for a **work** rather than an author. I guess it would be *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*?

Answer (score 27):

I would guess it is the works of Stanislaw Lem.  "Cyberiad" has been translated into English, widely published, and widely cited.  "Solaris" was made into a Hollywood movie.

Comment: When I read contemprory SF, I recognize more Lem than Asimov - because Lem dealt with cybernetics back when that was the term for Computer Sciences, and wrote about transhumanism before that was a word.

Comment: Did the Cyberiad really influence English SF much?

Comment: Came here to say this.  Stanislaw Lem is the most important non-English SF author of the 20th century. Clearly Jules Verne is the most important non-English author of the 19th century.

Comment: @WarrenP Not Heinlein or Asimov?

Comment: @user14111, we are talking about non-English writers. While Asimov was born in Russia, he wrote in English. And Heinlein is as American as apple pie.

Comment: Probably the Solaris movie drew more influence from Tarkovsky than Lem.

Comment: @horatio, probably. The movie was based on an English translation from an abridged French translation of the original Polish. Yet it is still a Hollywood movie based on a book by Stanislaw Lem.

Comment: @Dima Exactly my point. Heinlein and Asimov were American, not English.

Comment: I thought since the question talks about "English-speaking world", it was clear that "English authors" is a short-hand for "English language authors", not only authors from England.

Comment: Well, you thought, and the other person didn't think. :-)

Comment: @Dima I thought it was clear that "Not Heinlein or Asimov?" was shorthand for "Don't use 'English authors' as shorthand for 'English language authors'; bad idea, because the phrase 'English authors' is commonly used to mean 'authors who are English'."

Comment: @user14111: are you a Scot?

Answer (score 23):

Consider [Jules Verne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne). Considered by many to be one of the 'Fathers of Science Fiction', his works started being translated into English in 1852.  According to the Wikipedia article, he's the second most translated author in the world since 1979, and was probably the most translated during the 1960's & 70's.  Unfortunately, the article doesn't provide numbers on the translations by story/novel (and I don't know where that information could be obtained) but think about how many folks have read classics like '20,000 Leagues Under the Sea', 'Journey to the Center of the Earth' or 'From the Earth to the Moon'.

He is the most translated *novelist* in the world (148 languages according to UNESCO) see [NAJVS](http://najvs.org/about.shtml)

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if Pierre Boulle would count. Although the book *La Planète des singes* wasn't particularly popular outside of France, the various Planet of the Apes films which were (loosely) based on it have been extremely influential.

Comment: +1 | I am going to have to agree with you, Daniel. Verne is no doubt an undisputed world traveler but the Planet of the Apes is no joke for a movie series both in its original format and the recent upgrade for invading the mindspace of science fiction fans.

Answer (score 12):

If think Karel Čapek with his play [R.U.R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.U.R.) influenced SF quite heavily with his univrsally recognized word `robot`.

Comment: *The War with the Newts* is also very good; personally I find it more enjoyable than *R.U.R.* Haven't read anything else by him. Is *Absolute at Large* any good?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've read only War with the Newts, so I cannot be of help here.

Answer (score 9):

Even though the question is tagged as "written", a 1927 film "Metropolis" by Fritz Lang definitely deserves a mention, being an exceptionally influential work of Sci-Fi and seen by a considerable number of people.

Answer (score 7):

With Jules Verne and Stanislav Lem the best known non-english SF writers of the 19th and 20th century respectively, some earlier notable SF writers who were eventually widely circulated in English include:

**18th century:**

[Ludvig Holberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludvig_Holberg) Danish/Norwegian author publishing [Niels Klim's underground travels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Klim%27s_Underground_Travels) in 1741. Describes a solar system inside the earth with several inhabited planets. Widely published in several european languages

[Voltaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire) French writer and philosopher who wrote the 1792 short-story [Micromégas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microm%C3%A9gas) where Earth is visted by two aliens from Saturn and Sirius.

**17th century:**

[Johannes Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Kepler) German astronomer writing [Somnium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_Somnium) between 1620 and 1630. Contains detailed descriptions of how the earth would look like from the moon.

[Cyrano de Bergerac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_%28writer%29) French dramatist who wrote [Comical history of the states and empires of the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comical_History_of_the_States_and_Empires_of_the_Moon), published posthumously in 1657. Arthur C. Clarke credited this novel with the first description of rocket-powered space flight and the ramjet.

**2nd century:**

[Lucian of Samosata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucian) (AD 125 - AD 180) a Syrian satirist writing in Greek, who wrote [True History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_History) a satire of contemporary works which manages to include space travel, aliens and interplanetary warfare.

Answer (score 6):

[*We* by Yevgeney Zamyatin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_%28novel%29) (Russian, 1921), influenced e.g. George Orwell, Aldous Huxley, Ayn Rand, Kurt Vonnegut. That's quite a long reach.

Comment: Yes. Though "We" was first published in english, so it was not so much translated as written by someone with another mother-tongue. Other notable examples include Isaac Asimov who was born in Russia and who's mother-tongue was jiddisch. A mirror-reverse is the Sri Lankan author Arthur C. Clarke. He lived there from 1956 until his death in 2008 though his mother-tongue was of course english.

Comment: @Abulafia: Written in Russian. First published in English only because the Soviet censors banned it. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_%28novel%29#Publication_history) the first English translation was by [Gregory Zilboorg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Zilboorg).

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake!

Answer (score 5):

Some sort of "honorable mention" for Arkady and Boris Strugatsky's [Roadside Picnic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadside_Picnic#Cultural_influence) which turned into, among other things, the Tarkovsky film "Stalker", and their book [Monday [Begins|Starts] on Saturday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday_Begins_on_Saturday) (which is more soviet-science-fantasy)?

Heavily influential on me, at any rate. Pretty small sample size.